# Make eventlistener happen to my whole list

Tags: javascript

Somehow my eventlistener only works on the last list item. Can someone help me?

This is my code right now:

```
    (function(){
    // All items we'd like to add
    var navItems = [
        {href: 'http://instagram.com', text: 'Instagram'},
        {href: 'http://twitter.com', text: 'Twitter'},
        {href: 'http://facebook.com', text: 'Facebook'},
        {href: 'http://google.com', text: 'Google'},
        {href: 'https://youtube.com', text: 'Youtube'}
    ];

    // A few variables for use later
    var navElem = document.createElement("nav"),
        navList = document.createElement("ul"), 
        navItem, navLink;
        navElem.setAttribute('style','');
        navList.setAttribute('style','height: 100px;display:flex;');

    navElem.appendChild(navList);

    // Cycle over each nav item
    for (var i = 0; i < navItems.length; i++) {
        // Create a fresh list item, and anchor
        navItem = document.createElement("li");
        navLink = document.createElement("a");
        navItem.setAttribute('style','list-style-type:none; padding-top: 8px;background-color:rgb(209, 157, 12);margin: 30px 20px;border-radius:50px;');
        navLink.setAttribute('style','padding:0px 20px;text-decoration:none;font-size:20px;color:white;');



        // Set properties on anchor
        navLink.href = navItems[i].href;
        navLink.innerHTML = navItems[i].text;

        // Add anchor to list item, and list item to list
        navItem.appendChild(navLink);
        navList.appendChild(navItem);
    }
    
    navItem.addEventListener('mouseenter', () =>
    navItem.setAttribute('style','list-style-type:none; padding-top: 8px;background-color:rgba(209, 157, 12, 0.644);margin: 30px 20px;border-radius:50px;'));
    navItem.addEventListener('mouseleave', () =>
    navItem.setAttribute('style','list-style-type:none; padding-top: 8px;background-color:rgb(209, 157, 12);margin: 30px 20px;border-radius:50px;'));

    navList.children[0].className = "current";

    // Add list to body (or anywhere else)
    window.onload = function () {
        document.body.before(navElem);
    }

}());
```

GIF of my problem: https://gyazo.com/f70b7723958b24f2d8243af1e1434bd9

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: Anyway, as it currently seems, your intended result does not require `JavaScript` as it can be made with only `CSS` (am talking about the hover effect not creating dynamic elements even though the pseudo-elements could be a possible replacement for those dynamically created elements).

Comment: I strongly suggest to do this in CSS only

Comment: Your `navItem` is inside the `for`-loop. As such it only listen to events while the element is running within the loop and then reapplied to the current loop element

Comment: Im studying right now to become a Web developer and I'm having problems completing this task. The task is about creating a menu for HTML soly using JS. I'm able to create the menu and it works ok. But when trying to implement mouseenter it only works on my last list-item created. I want it to work like a hover effect on CSS on all my list-items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're adding event listener outside the for loop. The variable `navItem` holds reference to the last item after the loop is done. So, mouseenter and mouseleave are working only for the last item

Do something like this... Hope this helps!

```
function onMouseEnter (e) {
    var navItem = e.target;
    navItem.setAttribute('style','list-style-type:none; padding-top: 8px;background-color:rgba(209, 157, 12, 0.644);margin: 30px 20px;border-radius:50px;');
}

function onMouseLeave (e) {
    var navItem = e.target;
    navItem.setAttribute('style','list-style-type:none; padding-top: 8px;background-color:rgb(209, 157, 12);margin: 30px 20px;border-radius:50px;')
}

// Cycle over each nav item
for (var i = 0; i < navItems.length; i++) {
    // Create a fresh list item, and anchor
    navItem = document.createElement("li");
    navLink = document.createElement("a");
    navItem.setAttribute('style','list-style-type:none; padding-top: 8px;background-color:rgb(209, 157, 12);margin: 30px 20px;border-radius:50px;');
    navLink.setAttribute('style','padding:0px 20px;text-decoration:none;font-size:20px;color:white;');



    // Set properties on anchor
    navLink.href = navItems[i].href;
    navLink.innerHTML = navItems[i].text;

    // Add anchor to list item, and list item to list
    navItem.appendChild(navLink);
    navList.appendChild(navItem);
    navItem.addEventListener('mouseenter', onMouseEnter);
    navItem.addEventListener('mouseleave', onMouseLeave);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I've been struggling with this for hours! It works perfectly! :D

Answer (score 1):

you can make something like :
`for (var i = 0; i < navItems.length; i++) {
navItem = document.createElement("li");
navLink = document.createElement("a");
navItem.setAttribute('style','list-style-type:none; padding-top:
8px;background-color:rgb(209, 157, 12);margin: 30px 20px;border-
radius:50px;');
navLink.setAttribute('style','padding:0px 20px;text-
decoration:none;font-
size:20px;color:white;');

```
// Set properties on anchor
navLink.href = navItems[i].href;
navLink.innerHTML = navItems[i].text;

// Add anchor to list item, and list item to list
navItem.appendChild(navLink);
navList.appendChild(navItem);
navItem.addEventListener('mouseenter', () =>
navItem.setAttribute('style','list-style-type:none; padding-top: 
8px;background-color:rgba(209, 157, 12, 0.644);margin: 30px 
20px;border- 
radius:50px;'));
navItem.addEventListener('mouseleave', () =>
navItem.setAttribute('style','list-style-type:none; padding-top: 
8px;background-color:rgb(209, 157, 12);margin: 30px 20px;border- 
radius:50px;'));
}`
```

otherwise you can use just css hover

Comment: Thank you so much! I got it sorted with @lifelitemLearner007 answer. I forgot to write in the description but in this task I'm only allowed to write code in JavaScript. :)